Swagger schema for strongly typed Id
I am using records as a strongly typed id.
[TypeConveter(xxxxxx)]
public record ClientId(Ulid Value);

I created Entity Framework and Json converters that work properly.
Example
public class Request
{
    [TypeConverter(xxxxxxxx])
    public ClientId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Serializes to and the API responds properly to
{
    "ClientId": "someidstring",
    "Name": "some name"
}

However, Swagger shows the signature as
{
    "ClientId"{id:{}}:
    "Name": "string"
}

I would like Swagger to show the proper API definition:
{
    "ClientId": "someidstring",
    "Name": "some name"
}


I resolved the issue by creating a type for the class and adding to swager  gen
options.MapType<GatewayId>(() => new OpenApiSchema { Type = "string" });


[TypeConverter(typeof(GatewayIdTypeConverter))]

